# SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue.storefront.countryCode does not return the correct country code

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storefront

I try using `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue.storefront.countryCode` to get the correct countrycode of my appstore, but it returns the wrong one, and after I change my appstore's countrycode by changing appleid , it returns the same wrong one again, which means this api has cache.

Why????